# Need assistance with IF Exists then Insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exists

im trying to get this to run but cant figure out why its not. I am trying to create a pl/sql block that will read in 2 codes and make sure they exist before inserting:

```
declare
  v_old_atty_id in atty_rules.attorney_id%type;
  v_new_atty_id in atty_rules.attorney_id%type;

  type rule_array is varray(10000) of number; 
  v_rule rule_array;
begin

  select distinct rule_id
  bulk collect into v_rule
  from atty_rules
  where attorney_id = v_old_atty_id
  and date_activated <= sysdate
  and sysdate < nvl(date_deactivated, sysdate+1);

  if exists (select attorney_id
          from ORG_ATTYS
          where attorney_id = v_new_atty_id)
            for indx in 1..v_rule.count
            loop 
              insert into atty_rules (attorney_id,rule_id)
              values (v_new_atty_id, v_rule(indx));
            end loop 
   else
      dbms_output.put_line('Doesnt exist')
  end if;      
end;
```

Any direction will help a lot, thank you.

Comment: This will eventually be a procedure, im just writing it as a block for now

Comment: What exactly does happen when you run that code?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".  At the very least you're missing a `THEN` before the `FOR INDX...` statement.  In addition, I don't see where `v_new_atty_id` is ever given a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select count(attorney_id)
into v_count
from ORG_ATTYS
where attorney_id = v_new_atty_id

if v_count > 0 then
        for indx in 1..v_rule.count
        loop 
          insert into atty_rules (attorney_id,rule_id)
          values (v_new_atty_id, v_rule(indx));
        end loop 
 else
  dbms_output.put_line('Doesnt exist')
end if;
```

Comment: @user2405778 I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget to accept the answer to avoid low accepted rate and close the question. You can also vote for the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe don't use bulk collet at all, just do it in a one SQL statement, something like this:

```
v_old_atty_id := ...
v_new_atty_id := ...

insert into atty_rules (attorney_id,rule_id)
select v_new_atty_id, rule_id
from ( 
    select distinct rule_id
    from atty_rules
    where attorney_id = v_old_atty_id
      and date_activated <= sysdate
      and sysdate < nvl(date_deactivated, sysdate+1
)
WHERE   exists (select attorney_id
          from ORG_ATTYS
          where attorney_id = v_new_atty_id);
```